# ImagePickerController表示中にHUDを表示する方法

Tags: swift, swift4, uiimagepickercontroller

ImagePickerControllerで画像を選択後、画像を縮小して表示させようと考えています。
下記のコードを実行すると縮小の実行後、一瞬HUDが表示されるだけで、処理中にHUDが表示されません。

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    hud.show(in: self.view)

    let infoDic = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: info.map {key, value in (key.rawValue, value)})
    let image = infoDic[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage.rawValue] as! UIImage

    self.image = image.cropAndShrink()

    hud.dismiss()

    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

HUDは今はJGProgressHUDを使っています。
hud.show(in: self.view)をhud.show(in: picker.view)としても結果は変わりませんでした。
縮小処理中にHUDを表示させたいのですが、どのようにすればよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOSでは(実は他の多くのWindow/GUIシステムでも同じですが)、実際のUI画面の更新はイベント処理のメソッドが終わった後(にシステム側に画面更新のための時間が回ってきてから)行われます。

従って、同じイベントメソッドの中で`show`, `dismiss`あたりのメソッドを両方呼んでも、それがどんな表示になるのかは予想できないことになります。

とにかく一旦はイベントメソッドを終了しないといけないので、必然的に裏スレッドで処理を行う、マルチスレッドの知識が必要になります。

あたなの`cropAndShrink()`処理がスレッドセーフに書かれているとしたら、例えばこんな感じになります。

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    hud.show(in: self.view)

    guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        print("originalImage is not set")
        return
    }

    //時間のかかる処理は裏スレッド用のキューで実行
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let croppedImage = image.cropAndShrink()

        //UIの更新は必ずメインスレッドの中で行う必要がある
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.image = croppedImage
            self.hud.dismiss()
            self.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

ただし、上に書いたように`cropAndShrink()`がスレッドセーフでないと、この処理だとどこかでメモリが絡んだエラーになるかもしれません。お試しの上、うまくいかない点があるのなら、おしらせください。

---

さて、おしらせいただいたので、少々修正します。ご質問では`cropAndShrink()`だったのが、自己回答でお示しいただいた例だと`cropToBounds()`になっていたり、設定先が`self.image`ではなく`self.importedImage`になっていたりしますが、自己回答例の方に合わせることにします。

本当はご質問中のメソッド名・プロパティ名が正しいという場合には、適宜読み替えて下さい。

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    guard let loadedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        print("originalImage is not set")
        return
    }

    hud.show(in: self.view)
    self.dismiss(animated: true)

    //HUDの表示が有効になるように後からメインキューで実行することを登録するだけで、今のメソッドは直ちに終了
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.importedImage = loadedImage.cropToBounds()

        self.hud.dismiss()
    }
}
```

先ほどの例よりコードが短くなってしまいましたが、なぜ最初からこうしなかったのかというと、「`cropToBounds()`の(あるいは`cropAndShrink()`の)処理中にUIが固まってしまうから」というのが理由です。JGProgressHUDがどのようなものかは知らずに書いているのですが、例えばアニメーションを伴うようなものの場合、「UIが固まる」と言うのは、そのようなアニメーションも表示されなくなることを意味します。

`cropToBounds()`や`cropAndShrink()`がメソッド名の通りに1枚の画像をクロッピングしたり縮小したりするだけの物なら、かなりの高解像度画像でも、ユーザに「待たされた」なんて思わせるほどの時間はかかりません。

つまり上記のコードでも(そうなる原因は元のコードとは別ですが)「一瞬HUDが表示されるだけ」と言うのは変わらないかもしれません。

だとしたら、本末転倒ではあります(「ユーザを待たせるから、その間HUDを表示する」のではなく「HUDを表示するためにユーザを待たせる」ことになる)が、まぁ練習だと割り切って、`DispatchQueue.main...`の部分を以下のように書き換えると良いかもしれません。

```
    //HUDの表示が有効になるように0.5秒後からメインキューで実行することを登録するだけで、今のメソッドは直ちに終了
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        self.importedImage = loadedImage.cropToBounds()

        self.hud.dismiss()
    }
```

再度お時間をとってお試しいただければ幸いです。

---

ただし、練習用ではなく実際のアプリであれば「HUDを表示するためにユーザを待たせる」なんてのは、どう考えてもおかしいので

- `cropAndShrink()`とか`cropToBounds()`には大した時間がかからない
  ⇒そもそもHUDなんて表示せずに処理を進める

  (一度平均的にどれくらいの処理時間がかかるか計ってみると良いでしょう。)
- 画像処理が本当にユーザを待たせるほどの時間がかかる
  ⇒画像処理をスレッドセーフにして裏スレッドで実行する

  (最初に示したコードの形。HUDが表示されなかったと言うことなので、`self.dismiss(animated: true)`は移動させた方が良いでしょう。)

の、どちらかの形にした方が良いでしょう。

Comment: ご提示いただいたコードの要点を組み込んで実行した所、HUDは表示されませんでした。実際のコードではcropAndShrink()の後CoreGraphicsを扱っておりスレッドセーフではなかったのですが、cropAndShrink()の処理中はHUDが表示されるはずだと思われるので

Comment: 一度画面遷移させてからHUD表示させる方がいいのかもしれません。その場合どのように処理を連続的に行えばよいのでしょうか？

Comment: @Enuc さん、お示しいただいた自己回答の例をもとに追記いたしました。是非お試しいただいて結果をお聞かせください。

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfterの方で上手くいきました。と言っても画像の処理に時間は掛かっています。写真取込から表示に２分ほど掛かっており、どうも処理が普通では考えられない程重いようなので

Comment: 追って調査し、不明点があった場合にはまた別の質問を投稿させて頂きます。この度は細かな説明を含め案をご提示頂き有難うございました。

Comment: @Enuc さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。外部から取り込んだ数千万ピクセルの巨大画像に複雑なイフェクトをかけたとしても、2分はかかりすぎですね。もし別質問の形で投稿されることがあれば、また考えさせていただきます。

Comment: 解決しました。スレ違いですが一応ご報告を。UIImageからPixel情報を取り出す処理をコピペしてそのまま使っていたのが重い原因でした。

Comment: 具体的にはこの部分です。
        let pixelData = image.cgImage?.dataProvider?.data
        let data: UnsafePointer = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

Comment: @Enuc さん、わざわざのご報告ありがとうございます。ぱっと見た目特別遅くなりそうな処理にも見えないのですが、そんな部分が影響するのですね。解決できて何よりです。

Answer (score 0):

Timerを使用して複雑なタスクを切り分けて、戻った先のViewControllerでHUDを回すことには成功しました。以下ソースです。

```
class ExampleViewController: UIViewController,  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    private var isImageLoaded = false
    private var timer: Timer? = nil
    private var loadedImage: UIImage? = nil
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[.originalImage] {
            self.hud.show(in: self.view)
            isImageLoaded = true
            loadedImage = image
            self.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
    @objc func complicatedTask() {
        if isImageLoaded {
            isImageLoaded = false
            timer?.invalidate()
            self.importedImage = loadedImage.cropToBounds()
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(complicatedTask), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            self.hud.dismiss()
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(complicatedTask), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```